# Dictionary Flatten Prog in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d2={'a':'b', 'c':['d',{'e':'f'}], 'g':['h','i']}
```

How shall i flatten this dictionary using recursion so that the output would be as below:

```
res=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i']
```

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: what you have tried so far>

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
d2={'a':'b', 'c':['d',{'e':'f'}], 'g':['h','i']}

def flatten(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield k
            yield from flatten(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from flatten(v)
    else:
        yield d

out = [*flatten(d2)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
```